# CCLabelTTF Color - Gradient Possible?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I create label in my game using code:

```
 CCLabelTTF *label = [[CCLabelTTF alloc] initWithString:@"COMBO x1" dimensions:CGSizeMake(200,100)
                                                             alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter fontName:@"Helvetica" fontSize:HD_TEXT(25.0f)];
                label.color = ccc3(255,0,0);
                [self addChild:label z:0 tag:44];
```

This gives me a red label. But I'd like to have a gradient colored label.
is it possible using CCLabelTTF?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Use a bitmap font instead. Glyph Designer enables you to create gradients and shadows for the characters.

Hiero can also do this but I can't recommend this tool, it's full of bugs and has a terrible user interface.

Comment: Hi LearnCocos2D, thanks for your answer. I ended up making a sprite for it.